# Marrying non EU citizen

Tags: passport

I am a EU citizen. I'm currently living in london  and I'm looking to marry my partner  who's a non EU citizen and he's living in the UK with his parents and my partner is dependent  on his moms visa. But at the same time their visa is on pending.   Since I am an EU citizen  is there anyway that if I marry him he will be able to stay with me or either apply for  EU passport.

Answer (score 1):

He probably won't be able to apply for an EU passport, but that will depend on your country of citizenship.  Italy, for example, has an accelerated naturalization procedure for spouses of Italian citizens.

He will, however, be eligible to stay with you in the UK under the EU freedom of movement regime if you are married before the UK leaves the EU, and probably also under the new system that will replace it if you marry afterward.  See [Settled and pre-settled status for EU citizens and their families](https://www.gov.uk/settled-status-eu-citizens-families) for more information.